# No prototype in qml js

Tags: javascript, prototype, qml

I have following code

```
function Model(onChanged) {
    this.array = new Array();
    this.onChanged = onChanged;
}
Model.prototype.push = function(val) {
    this.array.push(val);
    if (typeof(this.onChanged) !== 'undefined') {
        this.onChanged();
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(Model.prototype));
console.log(JSON.stringify(Model.prototype.push));
```

And this gives me

```
{}
undefined
```

I've looked through some qml js code and there were same classes definitions so I can't get why this doesn't work for me. And autocomplete says that existing classes like Object, array, etc have prototype property. I tried to subclass them but got the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
console.log(Model.prototype);
console.log(Model.prototype.push);
```

JSON does not handle function or class definitions and therefore shows empty results.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but I still have problem: having Item with 
    `property variant model: null` in function inside this item `this.model = new Model.Model(this.update);` (js file was imported as Model) 
        `console.log(this.model.prototype.push);` gives undefined, while `this.model.array.push(1)` works fine

Comment: I guess you want to access the prototype of your `Model` class, not of it's instance: try `this.model.constructor.prototype`.

Comment: It is undefined too. But I don't really care about prototype, I just want to call `this.model.push`, but it says `TypeError: Result of expression 'this.model.push' [[object Object]] is not a function.` so I thought there is some problem with prototype or whatever.

Comment: `var m = new Model();
m.push(1)` in the js file works by the way.

Comment: There seems to be some problem with your JS importing, I guess: are you sure that your `Model.Model` is defined? If I run the code posted in your question, everything works fine (also `model.push(77)`). Maybe you should post some more of your code...

Comment: I made more tests, seems like I've some wrong property definition or accessing it wrongly: `property variant model: null` in function:            `var mm = new MModel.Model(this.update);
            mm.push(123);
            this.model = mm; this.model.push(1)` with this it works ok `mm.push(123);` here and make an error `this.model.push(1)` here

Comment: So I finally found out why it doesn't work. [Here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Store_JavaScript_object_references_in_QML_objects) is said that qml components can store only actual values inside properties, not references to some objects.